# Trying to save an integer on EditText and save on SQLite to calculate

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-sqlite, android-dialog

```
<TableRow>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Date1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
        android:text="@string/Date1"
        android:onClick="Date1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/SetDate1"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/EditText" />

</TableRow>
```

Here is my XML for the date I am trying to implement. So what I have so far is that
I will create a Dialog for picking the date and return that date to the EditText.

From there, I am trying to save the date in the SQLite so I can use second date to display the difference between two dates chosen by the user.

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(
                this, mDateSetListener, yr, month, day);
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID2:
        return new DatePickerDialog(
                this, mDateSetListener2, yr2, month2, day2);
    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
{
    public void onDateSet(
            DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
    {
        yr = year;
        month = monthOfYear+1;
        day = dayOfMonth;
        db.open();
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        long id = db.insertContact(month, day, yr);
        db.close();
        textBox.setText(yr + "/" + month + "/" + day);
    }

};
```

I just haven't uploaded the second Dialog to pick the date since it's just another repeat. After I put the dates in the SQLite or store it somehow, I want to add,multiply values to it and return that value to another EditText box. Also, is there a way to bake my Date Button's EditText to be not editable unless you click the Button to change EditText's content?

Thanks for reading and I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I really can't konw what do you want to do.
But EditText have two kinds of methods do not edit,one is enable is false,two is editable is false,but in the new android version editable is deprecate,but does not affect use.

Comment: So what I was trying to do was to bring up datepicker and pick the date, press OK and save those dates in the SQLite and do it again for the another date and use those dates to calculate how many days are in between.